# Flutter: How can Realtime database be searched in a streambuilder?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to search a realtime database in a streambuilder through a TextField which will take a TextEditingController.

The data is showing but unfortunately when i type in the TextField it doesn't Query/Search anything i type in the TextField, so how i can do the Query/Search method here?

Here is my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:idevice_me/providers/project_provider.dart';
    import 'package:idevice_me/screens/user_detail_screen.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
    
    
    
    class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      const HomeWidget({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
      TextEditingController searchData = TextEditingController();
      var dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
      var searchIng = dbref.orderByChild('users').onChildAdded;
      
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: (searchData.text.trim() == '') ? searchIng : dbref.child('users').onValue,
          builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              //----------------------------
              //USERID comes from here
              //----------------------------
             final userSnapshot = snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.toList();
              return Column(
                children: [
                 const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
                    child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Search',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,color: Colors.grey.shade400,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                ),
                                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                              ),
                              key: const ValueKey('search'),
                                
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                controller: searchData,
                           

 onChanged: (value){
                               searchData.text = value;
                            }
                            ),
                  ),
                         const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: userSnapshot.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, i)=> Column(
                        children: [
                          // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                UserDetailScreen.routeName, 
    
                                //--------------------------------------
                                //USERID should be here through snapshot
                                //--------------------------------------
    
                                arguments: userSnapshot[i].key.toString(),
                                );
                            },
                            
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                ListTile( 
                                  leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                                  title: Text(userSnapshot[i].child('username').value,),
                                  subtitle: Text(userSnapshot[i].child('email').value,),
                                  trailing: Text(userSnapshot[i].child('phone').value.toString()),
                                  onTap: (){
                                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                      UserDetailScreen.routeName,
                                      arguments: userSnapshot[i].key.toString()
                                      );
                                  },
                                ),
                                const Divider(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                      ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            return const Center(child: Text('There is something wrong!'),);
          },
          );
    
          
      }
    
     
        
      }
```

Comment: You could use onChange property on TextField to call the method for fetching data whenever any changes occur in the text field.

Comment: Didn't work :'(

Answer (score 1):

You're listening to different events from Firebase between searching and not-searching cases:

```
                                          // 
var searchIng = dbref.orderByChild('users').onChildAdded;
  
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: (searchData.text.trim() == '') ? searchIng : dbref.child('users').onValue,
                                                                           //
```

These two events are quite different:

- `onChildAdded`: fires for each **child** node under the path you read, or that matches your query.
- `onValue`: fires once with a single snapshot that contains all child nodes under the path you read, or that matches your query.

So when you use `onValue` here, you need to loop over the child nodes in your code. If you use `onChildAdded` however, the Firebase SDK already does that loop for you, and you don't need it in your code.

Since you seem to expect a list here `snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.toList()`, I recommend listening for `onValue` in both cases.

This should at least make both you search and non-search case show the list of users.

---

To get the actual searching working, you will need to use a query:

```
dbref.child('users').orderByChild('username').equalTo('Abdallah').onValue
```

Comment: So you mean do it like this: TextEditingController searchData =  TextEditingController();
  var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('users');
  Query search = dbRef.orderByChild('users'); --> StreamBuilder(
      stream: (searchData.text.trim() == '') ? search.onValue : dbRef.onValue,

Comment: I tried to do it but unfortunately it didn't work it still returns all of the data in ('users') it doesn't return what i'm searching for :'(

Comment: You're not searching for anything yet, so that is to be expected. I just fixed some of the bugs in your code, not all of them. --- I added an example of how to do a simple query to my answer too.

Comment: Frank thank you, you are my Flutter HERO Great! dbref.child('users').orderByChild('username').equalTo('Abdallah').onValue, worked as expected, but the only thing now is what if we need to get the data through a TextField! i tried to get data from equalTo(searchData.text.trim() --> (this is the TextEditingController) ) and then i went to the TextFiel (controller: searchData) but it didn't work :(, so what is the best practice to do that!